# Como cambiar un str a int en un texto para poder realizar operaciones? En Kivy, Python

Tags: python, android, ios, app, kivy

Estoy intentado crear una app con Kivy y Python
La app inicia bien, sin problema, cuando llego a la pantalla keyboard, que es como si fuera un teclado de calculadora, al apretar los numeros no tengo problema, el problema llega con uno de los botones que quiero crear que es de sumar +1 al valor que este escrito en el display, el cual me devuelve error y no acabo de entender bien como poder hacer esa función

Adjunto trozos resumidos del codigo de la app, en este vereis marcados donde creo que esta el Error

En mi Main.py (Resumido)

```
class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

GUI = Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class MainApp(App): #Creamos la classe de la APP
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self,screen_name):
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']            # Obtenemos el screenmanager del archivo main.kv
        screen_manager.current = screen_name

    def ch_m (self, i):                             #Metodo para sumar +1 con boton CH+1 al resultado de KeyboardScreen
        # <<<<<< ERROR!!!! >>>>>>>>
        resultado = int(self.root.ids['keyboard_screen'].ids['entry'])
        resultado.text = resultado + 1
        #print(resultado)
```

pasamos por el main.kv (resumido)

```
#:include kv/keyboardscreen.kv
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        StartScreen:
            name: 'start'
            id: 'start'
        FaderScreen:
            name: 'fader_screen'
            id: 'fader_screen'
        KeyboardScreen:
            name: 'keyboard_screen'
            id: 'keyboard_screen'
```

llegamos al keyboardscreen.kv (Resumido)

```
    BoxLayout:
        id: calculator                                                     #Display donde aparece el Texto
        display: entry
        size_hint_y : 0.2
        size_hint_x : 0.8
        pos_hint: {'x':0.15,'y': 0.78}
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            input_type: 'number'
            font_size: 32
            multiline: False


    FloatLayout:                                                    #Botones KeyBoard
        Button:
            text: '7'
            size_hint_y : 0.1
            size_hint_x : 0.1
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05 , 'y': 0.6}
            on_release: entry.text += self.text

.
.
.
.
        Button:                                                     # <<<<<< ERROR!!!!
            text: 'CH+'
            size_hint_y : 0.1
            size_hint_x : 0.1
            pos_hint: {'x':0.35 , 'y': 0.5}
            on_release: app.ch_m(entry.text)
```

deberia hacer como una calculadora... pero al intentar pasar por el metodo app.ch_m(entry.text)
aparece este error...

> ```
>   File "C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\Art-Net Project\kv\keyboardscreen.kv", line 113, in ><module>
>     on_release: app.ch_m(entry.text)
>  File "C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\Art-Net Project\main.py", line 37, in ch_m
>     resultado = int(self.root.ids['keyboard_screen'].ids['entry'])
> KeyError: 'keyboard_screen'
> ```

Alguna idea de como hacer que el resultado sea un int y poder manejarlo? o como poder usar una variable de la mainapp en los parametros de kv??

Comment: No es error por conversión. El error indica que la clave `keyboard_screen` No existe. Revisa bien la documentación y ve si no ha cambiado eso o si es tu propia implementación revisa que el nombre de la calve esté bien escrito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale si estaba usando el id: con '' '' y por eso no lo llamaba bien, aunque también he cambiado el método def ch_m el cual queda como os muestro a continuación

- Este método hace que sume +1 al numero mostrado en el display al soltar el botón CH+ del teclado numérico de la APP
- También hace que si no hay nada escrito al dar ValueError ya que no puede sumar un numero un valor que no existe nos muestre el str 'Error' en el Display

  > ```
  > def ch_m (self, i):        #Metodo para sumar +1 con boton CH+1 al resultado de KeyboardScreen
  >     try:
  >         input_text = str(self.root.ids['keyboard_screen'].ids['entry'].text)
  >         ch_m_text = int(input_text) + 1
  >         self.root.ids['keyboard_screen'].ids['entry'].text = str(ch_m_text)
  >     except:
  >         ValueError
  >         self.root.ids['keyboard_screen'].ids['entry'].text = 'Error'
  >         return self.root.ids['keyboard_screen'].ids['entry'].text
  > ```

i en el archivo .kv solo llamo a la función

```
    Button:                                                    
        text: 'CH+'
        size_hint_y : 0.1
        size_hint_x : 0.1
        pos_hint: {'x':0.35 , 'y': 0.5}
        on_release: app.ch_m(entry.text)
```